# Can you change specific CSS properties for a partial in a view?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I render a partial 'calendar/show' in two separate views. In one view (view A), it looks great and the font sizes are what I need, but in the other view (view B), the font size is too large.

I am wondering whether it's possible to change font-size just for this partial without affecting the other in the other view. This is the code I'm using (view B):

```
<%= render partial: '/calendars/show', locals: {} %>
```

Comment: Pass a local variable like: `locals: {:sheets => ['foo.css']}`. And in partial, check if sheets variable is present, iterate over it and `include_stylesheets` ?

Comment: @kiddorails Do you mind expanding this as an answer? I am new to Rails so I'm not fully sure what you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not a rails issue, but more like a css issue. If you want to control the font size different for both views, just wrap it with a `div`:

```
<div class="calendar-a">
  <%= render 'calendars/show' %>
</div>
```

vs:

```
<div class="calendar-b">
  <%= render 'calendars/show' %>
</div>
```

This solution would be much cleaner than making the partial require specific locals in order to determine in which view it is rendered.

Comment: id selector is more efficient than class selector.

Comment: Yeah, in terms of css selector performance, for sure. But what if there are multiple calendars on the same page? Adding IDs here seems a bit overengineered.

Comment: The OP wan't clear about whether there will be more than one instance. But still, you can just assign different IDs to the `<body>` for each version (unless you meant to use direct child operator `>` in the selector).